# Solution to $y = x^x (1-x)^{(1-x)}$ for $x$

Tags: equation-solving

Does anyone have any insight to a symbolic Mathematica solution to this equation for $x$ in terms of y? Symbolic of any sort, just not numeric.

$$y = x^x  (1-x)^{(1-x)}$$

Comment: Note that `Solve[y == x^x, x]` works but `Solve[y == (1 - x)^(1 - x), x]` does not.

Comment: Usually, transcendental equations of even moderate complexity do not even admit closed-form solutions. Sometimes, you get lucky, as with the Lambert function, but more often than not, there just isn't one.

Comment: How taking the logs of both sides, then separate $x$ by itself in terms of all the others terms (which will have $x$ in them), you get $x=\frac{\ln(y)-ln(1-x)}{ln(x)-ln(1-x)}$ and then take series expansion of the RHS in $x$, and then equate the $x$ coefficients, so you get $1=\frac{log(x)-log(y)}{log(x)^2}$ and now solve this for $x$ which gives `E^(1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 Log[y]]))` with complicated conditionals.  warning, I am not a math major, since the above might not make sense math wise, but something to look at.

Comment: @Nasser, here, taking the logarithms of both sides is not very productive; you end up with $\ln y= x\ln x + (1-x)\ln(1-x)$, which is no simpler than what we started with.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. yes, but that is what I mean, now solve for $x$ from the above, and take series expansion of the RHS, then equate the $x$ coeffcients.  There will be one term in the series with $x$ in it. That is what I meant.

Comment: …but in any case, this is more a math question than a *Mathematica* question.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I agree. This is a math question really, not Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser, okay, then what happens if you substitute your candidate solution into the original equation?

Comment: If you offset x by adding 1/2 you might use Mathematica to gain a bit of feeling for your function: Plot[{Re[(x + 1/2)^(x + 1/2) (1/2 - x)^(1/2 - x)], Im[(x + 1/2)^(x + 1/2) (1/2 - x)^(1/2 - x)]} , {x, -5, 5}]

Comment: Might want to x-post to Math.Stackexchange, could get some insight there...

Comment: Dear friends: this IS definitely a mma question. Please see my solution which is surprising (and was new to me) and applies to a broad class of transcendetal equations.

Comment: People here are too fast in killing threads. Relax folks, give a little leeway to new users and see what happens... It's not like virginity in the Middle Ages.

Answer (score 7):

Why not take a suitable Mathematica comand literally?

Let y as a function of x be given by

```
y = x^x (1 - x)^(1 - x);
```

Aren't we just looking for x as a function of y?

So let's simply write down what we want

```
xx = InverseFunction[#^# (1 - #)^(1 - #) &];
```

This function gives the symbolic solution the OP asked for.

Indeed, we can take values

```
Table[xx[(1 + Random[])/2], {10}]

(*
Out[53]= {0.0537599, 0.00203679, 0.12122, 0.151892, 0.0588153, 0.316227, 0.28835, \
0.0545701, 0.115355, 0.0168024}
*)
```

we can Plot it

```
Plot[xx[yy], {yy, 1/2, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "InverseFunction x[y] if y = x^x(1-x)^(1-x)]", 
 AxesLabel -> {"y", "x"}]
(* 150523_plot _xx.jpg *)
```

[image]

We can take the drivative

```
D[xx[yy], yy]

(*
Out[65]= 1/((-1 - Log[1 - InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy]]) (1 - 
      InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy])^(
    1 - InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy])
     InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy]^
    InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][
     yy] + (1 + Log[InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy]]) (1 - 
      InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy])^(
    1 - InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy])
     InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy]^
    InverseFunction[#1^#1 (1 - #1)^(1 - #1) &][yy])
% /. yy -> 2/3

(*
Out[66]= 1/((-1 - 
      Log[1 - Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
          0.140276506997464737195}]]) (1 - 
      Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
        0.140276506997464737195}])^(
    1 - Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
       0.140276506997464737195}])
     Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
      0.140276506997464737195}]^
    Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
      0.140276506997464737195}] + (1 + 
      Log[Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
         0.140276506997464737195}]]) (1 - 
      Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
        0.140276506997464737195}])^(
    1 - Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
       0.140276506997464737195}])
     Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 
      0.140276506997464737195}]^
    Root[{-3 + 2 ((1 - #1)/#1)^#1 + 3 #1 &, 0.140276506997464737195}])
*)

% // N

(*
Out[67]= -0.82736
*)
```

And we can integrate it

```
Integrate[xx[yy], {yy, 1/2, 1}]
```

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \text{InverseFunction}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{\text{$\#$1}} (1-\text{$\#$1})^{1-\text{$\#$1}}\&\right][\text{yy}] \, d\text{yy}$$

```
NIntegrate[xx[yy], {yy, 1/2, 1}]

(*
Out[69]= 0.0589135
*)
```

Which is correct as we can see thus

```
NIntegrate[x^x (1 - x)^(1 - x), {x, 0, 1/2}]

(*
Out[74]= 0.308913
*)
```

from which we have to subtract the area of the rectangle below the minimum

```
1/2*x^x (1 - x)^(1 - x) /. x -> 1/2

(*
Out[71]= 1/4
*)

%% - %

(*
Out[72]= 0.0589135
*)
```

ok.

Remark: In order to just get the function plottet we could use

```
Off[Power::indet];
ParametricPlot[{y, x}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{1/2, 1}, {0, 1/2}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "x(y) for y = x^x(1-x)^(1-x)", AxesLabel -> {"y", "x"}]
On[Power::indet]
(* 150523_parametricplot.jpg *)
```

[image]

**EDIT #1**

Obviously you can solve many transcendental equations with this method in a very elegant an compact manner.
Examples are x == Tan[x], 1 == x Exp[-x], Cos[x] == x and so on.

Comment: +1 I never knew InverseFunction, however I did know about `InverseSeries` which you can use in this way expanded around 1/2: `Normal@InverseSeries[Series[x^x (1 - x)^(1 - x), {x, 1/2, 10}]]`

Comment: Excellent! - I did not know about InverseFunction either, and its just what I am looking for. I have been using InverseSeries around x=1/2 as Histograms suggested, but it gets flaky around x=1. I tested InverseFunction, and it is much superior. Thank you Dr. Hintze, and everybody else who contributed.

Comment: Actually, if you draw the function y[x] you can see that it has real values for x in 0-1, so the inverse function, restricted to reals, has two branches. One is the one you showed, the other one is the mirror of that with respect with the translated y axis at x=1/2. (It's like a "C"). And you can see that by exchanging the x and y axis in the plot of y[x] (there's a simple gesture that changes an "L" made with index and thumb into a "gun" that shows the required transformation to get the inverse of any plot, once one has seen that...)

Comment: ...in 0-1 AND it's not monotonic, SO...

Comment: @Peltio The suspense is killing me...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau :-) Er... that is just an addition to my comment above. When I realized I missed a bit it was to late too edit it... so I had to make a new comment. The ellipses are just 'cut&paste' indicators. Unless you are referring to the above closing ellipses. In that case there's no continuation. All I meant is that once one has seen that "L to gun" gesture, inverse functions are no longer a mistery... (<--- here we go again)

Comment: Here, I did it again. I wrote "to" instead of "too" and I corrected the wrong one. And now it's to late to fix it. I hate being me. :-)

Comment: @Peltio Yes, I meant the closing ellipses in the second comment. Thought it indicated there'd be a third one coming.

Comment: Yes, there are two solutions. I used InverseFunction to get the first (x) (apparently the largest) and then 1-x to get the other. The function I am using is f[x,c] where c=0 gives {x,1-x}, c=1 gives x and c=2 gives 1-x. Works great. Also, this was definitely an MMA question, sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Let me add that my proposal to use InverseFunction is not at all restricted to real values, as ca easily be checked outside the range 0 < x < 1.